# CodeIgniter valid_email() Function Not Working Properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter with the following code:

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<font color="red">', '</font>');
    $this->load->helper('email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Member name', 'required|trim|max_length[31]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Mailing address', 'required|trim|max_length[41]');
    # Additional fields here

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        # Go back to the form. This is not occuring.
    }
    else {
            # This view is being loaded, but with an error on the page. Picture below.
            $this->load->view('success_new', array('email' => set_value('email')));

    }
```

When the form is submitted, it is supposed to go back to the form if there was an error. The e-mail address I'm testing with is david@lemcoe.com, which is obviously valid. Why when I get to the success page, do I see the success message, plus "Invalid e-mail address?"

I have checked the view, checked the controller code, everything, and nowhere should it be outputting any errors if it passed validation. Is there a known issue with this `valid_email()` validation technique? If so, what is the best e-mail validation RegEx to use in this situation.

Here is the success_new view. Nowhere in the view does it echo any errors.

[image]

Comment: There is no issue with codeigniter email validation, I am using since a long time without facing any problem.

Comment: Can you post more of the code, like where you set this message?

Comment: Unrelated note: a valid e-mail address can use more than 50 characters. The [PHP team](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L503) claims "The maximum length of an e-mail address is 320 octets, per RFC 2821".

Comment: Code updated and a picture was added.

Comment: @David can you post view code, `success_new` i mean.

Comment: The only PHP in that view is `<?php echo $email; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say where that validation message is coming from. With the code you've posted there's no sign of `validation_errors()` which is IIRC what outputs the localised error messages to your view. It's been a number of years since I used CI. I would really need to see the full controller method and view code.

What I would say though is I remember big problems with the `valid_email` rule in the form validation class. It failed on many valid e-mail address formats, one common one I remember was e-mail addresses with `+` in the local user part. I also frequently see e-mail addresses of >50 characters on our mail servers which you're killing off.

I would suggest using PHP's built-in [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function in your own [CI form validation callback](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods) method... `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`